# How to get longitude and latitude when user tap on map?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I have inside my LinearLayout  with id=test_map.
How to get longitude and latitude when user tap on map ? In which function I can read this from event ?

Answer (score 0):

Extend Overlay and override method and override  `boolean   onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)` method. p will contain coordinates.

to add newly created overlay use `mapView.getOVerlays().add(myOverlay);`